# Verify mail was sent from unit tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, email

I have some unit tests in my Django 1.2.4 app. One of the tests needs to verify that emails are sent under certain conditions. How can I do this?

Ideally it'd be programmatic, but it'd also be nice to print the email body out to the console.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The latest Django testing documentation has an [Email Services](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) section.

Then you just do something like:

```
from django.core import mail

print mail.outbox[0].body
```

The HTML version is handled via attached alternative mimetypes, which you can access (if you attached one) such as

```
content, mimetype = mail.outbox[0].alternatives[0]
```

Outbox objects are EmailMessages, [further documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

Comment: Thanks also for showing how to get the email message itself (the Django docs only show how to get the outbox's subject). Do you know a reference for the other properties of the outbox, e.g. an html version of the message?

Comment: The HTML version is handled via attached alternative mimetypes, which you can access (if you attached one) such as `content, mimetype = mail.outbox[0].alternatives[0]`. Outbox objects are EmailMessages, which are further documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage.

Comment: I *so* wish the Django docs explained that as clearly as @mrooney, and that there was a way to award him some rep.